# A question about linear transformations mapping straight lines to straight lines

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Obviously, a linear transformation over a space maps all straight lines to other straight lines.

My question is: is the converse true? That is, if we're looking at a space after some transformation and we're observing that all straight lines were mapped to straight lines, does that imply a linear transformation? (Lines are understood as finite and infinite collections of points that are aligned, well, in a line)

**EDIT:** The comments mention affine transformations which fullfil the above condition but are not linear since they also involve translation. I think I'll reask then: Is every transformation that maps ALL lines to lines necessarily affine?

Comment: Well, it's definitely false in $\Bbb R^1$. Linear transformations can be defined over all sorts of vector spaces over lots of different fields. Are you talking specifically about $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: No, it could be an affine transformation as well.

Comment: in $\mathbb{R}^2$ take a vector $(a,b)\neq 0$ then the map $(x,y)\mapsto (x+a,y+b)$ is certainly not linear.

Comment: A trickier question: in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for $n\ge2$, is every map which sends lines to lines **and** the point zero to zero linear?

Comment: @MikeEarnest I think I'll refine my question accordingly

Answer (score -3):

not always but converse will  be true iff T(x) that is a function of x .You can suppose y=T(x) represents the line that Passes through origin